# CSS: Work-around "font-weight: lighter" not working

Tags: css

I can't see any difference between the rendered result of

```
font-weight: normal
```

and

```
font-weight: lighter
```

I use FireFox 50.0 on linux.

Is there a way to make `font-weight: lighter` be visible?

The numbers (100..900), don't show any noticeable change in my eyes.

Here is an example page: https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Eigenschaften/Schriftformatierung/font-weight

## Background

My font does not support lighter font-weights. Yes, I could use a different font. But changing the font is beyond my scope.

Comment: The `font-weight` property only works when the weight variants are available for that font.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:** This answer is a suggestion to use a `font-family` with extended weights to be able to go lower than `300`, considering the question in case.

To best illustrate it, the following snippet example was created: ("Muli" font-family was used just for demonstration and can be found in [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com)):

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}
.thin {
  font-weight: 200;
}
.light {
  font-weight: 300;
}
.regular {
  font-weight: 400;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: 600;
}
.extraBold {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.black {
  font-weight: 800;
}
.extraBlack {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:200,300,400,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
<p class="thin">weight 200</p>
<p class="light">weight 300</p>
<p class="regular">weight 400</p>
<p class="bold">weight 600</p>
<p class="extraBold">weight 700</p>
<p class="black">weight 800</p>
<p class="extraBlack">weight 900</p>
```

Comment: Yes, great. This works if you font supports `font-weight`. What can I do if the font does not support this?

Comment: I don't know the color of the text. The CSS styling is not done in my module. That's why I use opacity. Please keep on telling me what I am doing wrong. I am curious if there is a better solution.

Comment: @Sydon Seperation of Concerns: I don't know the underlying font. I can do some styling by changing the font-size or making in bold. But I don't now the color of the font-type.

Comment: maybe I misunderstood you. I thought you suggested to use "color: lightgray". That's why I said, that I don't know the color. If text color is green, then lightgray would be the opposite of the desired result: instead of making it less visible, it would be an eye catcher :-)

Comment: Ahh no, I misunderstood.. sorry, the color would be dynamic? I assumed it was black all the time.. but man, if you wish for weight flexibility and also have different colors/weights, you should really consider to embed a proper font-family, it could even be imported via CSS from your styles guy or whoever is there. So in your case you could use the opacity as a hack yea, but you are basically differentiating transparencies, It wouldn't have much to do with font-weight.

Comment: yes, you are right. I will talk to people who can change the font type.

Answer (score -2):

I found a work-around this: [css opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

Here is a screenshot which shows three styles:

- normal
- `font-weight: bold`
- `opacity: 0.5`

[image]

Comment: Depends on the font-family used, very few go below 300, also browsers vary on their rendering, technically what you are doing is not lighter but more transparent.

Comment: @Syden yes I know. Up to now this was the best solution I could find. Improvements are welcome.

Comment: You could use a font-family with thinner weights.

Comment: @Syden what benefits has using a font-family with thinner weights?

Comment: You would be able to use it's extended weights (less than 300). For example Roboto has 100 but not 200: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Open+Sans|Roboto but if you search google fonts you will find some offer 200 as well.

Comment: @guettli this is super hacky and will unlikely render the same way on different combinations of browser+OS... the only way to treat text correctly is to use a font. <3 typography

Comment: @zeropaper how can I know if the client has a font which supports thinner weights? The example of user Syden works in my browser, but the same browser displays the font of my application as usual (not thinner). How to choose a font-family which has thinner weights?

Comment: You have to choose (from Google fonts for example) and embedded/add the font by yourself. With font-face.